# How to get AppRole for azure active directory user using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Graph API to access group and group members of azure active directory. Is there any way to get AppRole for user with Microsoft Graph API, as
there is one example I found "[How to check if an azure active directory user is already in an approle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219361/how-to-check-if-an-azure-active-directory-user-is-already-in-an-approle)", but it uses Azure Active Directory Graph API

Is AppRole functionality available with Microssoft Graph or shall I switch to Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient?

Answer (score 1):

I tried [Get appRoleAssignment api](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/approleassignment_get) in graph explorer with beta version:

```
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/appRoleAssignments/{id}
```

but got the `Unsupported segment type` error , seems microsoft graph api is not exposing appRoleAssignments on users entity .  You could query that using azure ad graph api instead .

Comment: Can GAP  section of https://dev.office.com/blogs/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph be updated to include appRoleAssignments?

Comment: You could add a comment on that document . But since [Get appRoleAssignment api](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/approleassignment_get) has the rest api , i think they will work on that to finish the feature .